# Server time is off by 5 minutes

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, timezone

I need to create a cron job to run a script. Changed the server timezone to Eastern following the first option in [this guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/change-timezone-in-linux/). The timezone was changed successfully but when I run `date` I'm noticing that the time is about 5 minutes ahead of [time.gov](http://time.gov/HTML5/) (and my local machine).

Any idea what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to setup NTP.

See:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

Extra content here.

Comment: I recently rebooted the server and now the issue seems to have been resolved. Not sure if it was the reboot but I didn't do anything else. Is it possible that the reboot did it?

Comment: I used chrony as suggested following the link instructions. At first the chrony stats were showing that my instance was 6 minutes ahead, but as time went by chrony was syncing the time and 30 minutes later it was on sync, no need to restart the instance.